# Table Valued User Defined Functions in DB2 Z/OS

Tags: db2, zos

Does anyone know if DB2 v9.1 z/OS supports Table Valued User Defined Functions?

This is what I am trying to create but I keep getting the error message below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION func_test(v_vchCol CHAR(10))
RETURNS TABLE(col_a char(10), row_cnt integer)
LANGUAGE SQL
SPECIFIC FUNCINFO
NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
return 
  select col_1, count(*)
    from SCHEMA_NAME.TEST1
   where col_1 = v_vchCol 
   group by col_1;
```

Error Message:

> ERROR [56038] [IBM][DB2] SQL0969N There is no message text
>   corresponding to SQL error "-4700" in the message file on this
>   workstation. The error was returned from module "DSNHSMS1" with
>   original tokens "". SQLSTATE=56038

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createfunctionexternaltable.htm), but it appears to require [new function mode](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.inst/src/tpc/db2z_availabilitynewfn.htm) which [apparently isn't enabled yet](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n4700.htm) in the DB2 instance you're connected to.

Comment: Any way you could update the links? They are no longer valid.

Comment: @AndreyBelykh This question was about DB2 9.1 for z/OS.  Support for that product was discontinued 27-Jun-2014.  Documentation for that product is limited to PDFs and soon-to-be removed BookManager.